# How to change OrganizationName after setup /p

Tags: active-directory, exchange, schema

I am working on cloning our primary AD DC to create a development environment. I have exported the relevant data from AD using `ldifde` but in order to import it on the new server, I need the Exchange Schema installed.

I obtained the Exchange install media and did this:

```
Y:\Applications\Current Windows\Exchange 2010>Setup /ps

[blah, blah, blah... success]

Y:\Applications\Current Windows\Exchange 2010>Setup /p /OrganizationName:"Computer Science"

Welcome to Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 Unattended Setup

By continuing the installation process, you agree to the license terms of
Microsoft Exchange Server 2010. If you don't accept these license terms,
please cancel the installation. To review these license terms, please go to
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=150127&clcid=0x409/

Press any key to cancel setup................
No key presses were detected.  Setup will continue.
Preparing Exchange Setup

    Copying Setup Files              ......................... COMPLETED

No server roles will be installed

Performing Microsoft Exchange Server Prerequisite Check

    Organization Checks              ......................... COMPLETED
 Setup is going to prepare the organization for Exchange 2010 by using 'Setup /P
repareAD'. No Exchange 2007 server roles have been detected in this topology. Af
ter this operation, you will not be able to install any Exchange 2007 server rol
es.

Configuring Microsoft Exchange Server

    Organization Preparation         ......................... COMPLETED

The Microsoft Exchange Server setup operation completed successfully.
```

However, I got the OrganizationName wrong and I want to change it to the correct one to match the exported AD data:

```
Y:\Applications\Current Windows\Exchange 2010>Setup /p /OrganizationName:"Computer Science Department"

Welcome to Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 Unattended Setup

By continuing the installation process, you agree to the license terms of
Microsoft Exchange Server 2010. If you don't accept these license terms,
please cancel the installation. To review these license terms, please go to
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=150127&clcid=0x409/

Press any key to cancel setup................
No key presses were detected.  Setup will continue.
Preparing Exchange Setup

    Copying Setup Files              ......................... COMPLETED

No server roles will be installed

 Exchange organization name cannot be specified. There already exists an Exchang
e organization with name 'Computer Science'.

Exchange Server setup encountered an error.

Y:\Applications\Current Windows\Exchange 2010>
```

Obviously, it failed. How can I change the Exchange schema OrganizationName?

Comment: FWIW, When I did all this for our test environment, I used a virtual environment and made all the changes while running on a snapshot.  That way when I screwed it up (and I did!), I could roll back and try again.  This worked for AD in a single DC environment.  once I was certain it looked good, I roll the snapshot into the base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Exchange has not been actually installed anywhere (or if it's there, but you can afford completely losing it), you can remove all Exchange-related informations from Active Directory and the run the preparation steps again.

You need to remove the Exchange Organization object in the Configuration partition of your Active Directory forest; the easiest way to accomplish that is firing up the Active Directory Sites and Services console, enable the viewing of the "Services" node (disabled by default), then delete the node called "Microsoft Exchange" (under which you will have another node representing your organization). You can also do the same thing using ADSIEdit and connecting to the Configuration directory partition.

You should also remove the OUs "Microsoft Exchange Security Groups" and "Microsoft Exchange System Objects" from Active Directory.